# Quickly create an entry in the side bar Launcher

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity

How to quickly create a Launcher entry for a certain command, e.g. `sudo <command>`?

I remember older Linux (Ubuntu and others) distributions where I could right-click the panel (or desktop) and select "Create Launcher".

Comment: Do you mean add a second command to a pre-existing Launcher entry or a new entry?

Comment: Adding it for a new command is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

### Unity Launcher editor

You can use [Unity Laucher Editor](https://code.launchpad.net/unity-launcher-editor) to create and modify launcher icons using only a GUI. Keep in mind that the status of this application is *experimental*; expect some glitches.

To install it, run the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr && cd && bzr branch lp:unity-launcher-editor
```

Once installed, you can run it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and executing

```
~/unity-launcher-editor/ule
```

[image: screenshot]

### Traditional approach

#### Create a new launcher item

1. Install **gnome-panel** using the Software Center or with the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and execute the command

   ```
   gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
3. Depending on the application, choose either **Application** and `gksudo <command>` or **Application in terminal** and `sudo <command>`.
4. Open Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and go to

   ```
   ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
5. Drag the newly created *.desktop* file to the launcher.

#### Add a command to an existing launcher item

1. Search for the launcher icon's *.desktop* file; it's usually in one one these two folders:

   ```
   ~/.local/share/applications
   /usr/share/applications
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and execute the command

   ```
   gedit <.desktop file>
   ```
3. Add the following line to **[Desktop Entry]**.

   ```
   Actions=sudo;
   ```

   If an `Actions=` line already exists, append `sudo;` to it.
4. At the end of the file, add the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Action sudo]
   Name=Run as Root
   Exec=gksudo <command>
   ```
5. Save the modified *.desktop* file in `~/.local/share/applications`. If the original file is in a different folder, remove the old launcher icon (right-click, *Unlock from Launcher*) and drag the new file to the launcher.

Comment: Thank you very much. One related question: `~/.gnome/apps` also seems to contain similar `.desktop` files. Is this for backward compatibility?

Comment: I've tried to create an item with the command `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications`, but unfortunately, it fails to launch. :( Other commands like `gksudo truecrypt` work.

Comment: 1. Do or did you have GNOME installed? I don't even have a `~/.gnome` directory on my computer... 2. Try to run it from a terminal to see why it fails.

Comment: Regarding Gnome - I have the standard Ubuntu 12.04 installed, so I guess, that Gnome is not installed. Launching the command from the Terminal works fine.

Comment: Interesting. I have Ubuntu 12.04 as well. Maybe some application you installed had that path hardcoded... I've edited my answer to add a GUI-based approach.